# Validar nombre de archivo a leer

Tags: c#

Tengo un `array` de archivos que se toman dentro de una carpeta, con el `foreach` estoy recorriéndolos, pero solo necesito que lea alguno que inicien de cierta forma, estos inician con el nombre "**detail_log**" seguido de números al azar.

¿Cómo puedo validar que inicie con esa primera palabra?

```
for (int i = 0; i < name_folder.Length; i++)
{
   //file debe iniciar con "detail_log....."
   // Si es asi entonces sigue, si no incrementa y va a la sig. posicion

}
```

Comment: string.contains?

Comment: Donde está el Array y el Foreach?, indica por favor el código completo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `StartsWith()` de tipo `string`, te recuperaría los archivos que comienzan por un determinado patrón.

Sería algo así:

```
        foreach (var name_folder in array_archivos)
        {
            if (name_folder.StartsWith("detail_log"))
            {
                // Tu código aquí..
            }
        }
```